# Yii2 Select2 - selected value on update - junction table (many to many)

Tags: yii2, many-to-many, jquery-select2

I am successfully inserting new rows in my junction table (userlocations) on action create and I successfully update them on action update but the problem is on ation update the location_id field is always empty. It should retrieve the location_id's from userlocations table and populate the field on update but it doesnt.

Database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFjdz.png

UserController:

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\User;
use backend\models\UserSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

use backend\models\Locations;
use backend\models\Userlocations;

class UserController extends Controller
{

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Lists all User models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single User model.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new User model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new User();
    $locations = ArrayHelper::map(Locations::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
    $userlocations = new Userlocations();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

        $model->setPassword($model->password);
        $model->generateAuthKey();

        $userlocations->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

        if ($model->save() && !empty($userlocations->location_id)){

            foreach ($userlocations->location_id as $location_id) {
                $userlocations = new Userlocations();
                $userlocations->setAttributes([
                    'location_id' => $location_id,
                    'user_id' => $model->id,
                ]);
                $userlocations->save();
            }
        }

        return $this->redirect(['user/index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'locations' => $locations,
            'userlocations' => $userlocations,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates an existing User model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $locations = ArrayHelper::map(Locations::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
    $userlocations = new Userlocations();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        Userlocations::deleteAll(['user_id' => $id]);

        $userlocations->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

        if (!empty($userlocations->location_id)){
            foreach ($userlocations->location_id as $location_id) {
                $userlocations = new Userlocations();
                $userlocations->setAttributes([
                    'location_id' => $location_id,
                    'user_id' => $model->id,
                ]);
                $userlocations->save();
            }
        }

        return $this->redirect(['user/index']);
    } else {

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'locations' => $locations,
            'userlocations' => $userlocations,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing User model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

/**
 * Finds the User model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return User the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

}

User model:

```
class User extends \common\models\User
{

public $password;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'User';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['username', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
        [['username'], 'unique', 'message' => 'Username already taken!'],
        [['email'], 'unique'],
        [['password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
        'password_hash' => 'Password Hash',
        'password_reset_token' => 'Password Reset Token',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
    ];
}
```

}

My form:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\select2\Select2;

use backend\models\Locations;

?>

<div class="user-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($userlocations, 'location_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Locations::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'size' => Select2::MEDIUM,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a location ...', 'multiple' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList(['10' => 'Active', '0' => 'Inactive']) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: @PurpleHaze Can you show me your User model.I see no location_id field in User table

Comment: Show me a snapshot of the post data that is sent to the server.You can use the network tab in chrome developer tools to see your post data

Comment: If you are making changes in more than one table,always use it in a transaction

Comment: @KiranMuralee I made some minor changes trying to make it work but the result is the same. I also updated the full user model user controller and user form. Here is the post data I send to the server: http://oi65.tinypic.com/okspwk.jpg

Comment: Thanks I will look into it

Comment: Please take a look at user controller actionUpdate in the else section. It seems if I add ' $userlocations = $userlocations::find()->where(['user_id' => $id])->one(); ' above the return, the actionUpdate will populate the select2 field but only with one value even if I have more than one value in the junction table. I think there is the problem but I cant figure out what I need to do.

Comment: I may require further inputs from you so pls stay connected.Lets solve it :)

Comment: Sure I'll be here, I can give u all the asistance you need I want to solve this asap :D Thanks alot!!

Comment: Sure. This is the Userlocation table: http://oi68.tinypic.com/1zgc393.jpg and this is the user/update page http://oi68.tinypic.com/263h6qv.jpg. The problem is I should see the 2 locations from junction table instead of 'select a location...' . The action/create and action/update work as expected inserting and updating values accordingly in the junction table. THe only problem is the select2 field always showing 'select a location...' instead of showing values from database.

Comment: Actually I had a confusion in understanding,did you mean that you are comfortable in updating but the view selected for update is not correctly listing the locations previously updated.Am I right

Comment: Ok I understood your problem

Comment: If you can skype I can share you my screen and show you exactly what is happening

Comment: Ok you are using a yii2 widget for select2 kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2

Comment: I think there is some problem with the plugin usage.Let me see the plugin usage documentation and will come back.

Comment: Most of the yii2 developers skipped your question as the question is not clear I think,they may not be aware of your real problem.I will edit your question

Comment: Sure, go ahead, and thanks alot for sticking around :D

Comment: try giving a 'value' => ['USA', 'CANADA'] (give any two location name already in database) to the select2 widget field and inform me whether you are getting the tags in Location field

Comment: If you are getting the tags then try to give like 'value' => [1=>'USA', 2=>'CANADA'] and inform me

Comment: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-tags.  This link will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple location select, use the plugin code as given below.

```
 <?= Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'Userlocations[location_id]',
        'value' => $location_ids, // initial value
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Locations::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select your locations...', 'multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'tags' => true,
            'maximumInputLength' => 10
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

$location_ids will be the location array you have previously selected during creation time.Also remember when you are making changes for more than one table,make sure you do it in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks alot Kiran :D